# Diminishing roots of a equations

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have $f(x)=x^3-6x^2+12x-8$ and need to diminish each root by $3$ without actaully calculating each root.  I can achive this by by setting $$f(x)=(x+3)^3-6(x+3)^2+12(x+3)-8$$

This can be easily expanded using binomial theorem. But what if $f(x)$ is of degree $7?, 10?$
How would I proceed in those cases without expading, say, power $9$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The exact question was to find coefficiants of $x^2$ and $x^0$. So I do need to expand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

*Taylor's formula*  is an exact formula for polynomials.

Comment: thats... genius, mate. Thank you!